# Create highscore value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a highscore marker, but it keeps its value always in 0. Help please

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class score : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform jugador;
    public Text scoreText;
    public Text highScore;

    void Start(){
        highScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("HighScore", 0);
    }

    void Update () {
        scoreText.text = jugador.position.z.ToString("0");
    }
    public void HighScore(){
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("HighScore", jugador.position.z.ToString("0");
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried getting and setting floats instead of strings?

Answer (score 0):

**Setting Score:**

```cs
public Text score;
public Text highscore;
private float currentscore = 0;
```

To increase the score we can simply set the `currentscore` to the current `position.z` and then update our `Text` Component.

**Increasing Score:**

```cs
private void Update () {
    // Get the current Z position of jugador and round to a whole number.
    currentScore = jugador.position.z;
    // Set our scoreText Component to the currentScore.
    scoreText.text = currentScore.ToString("0");
}
```

After that we set the Highscore to the `currentscore` with the `SetHighScore()` Method in our `Score`.

**Set HighScore:**

```cs
private void SetHighScore() {
   // Set HighScore to the currentScore if it's bigger than the current HighScore.
   if (currentScore > PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0.0f)) {
       PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighScore", currentScore);
   }
}
```

To actually see our new score when we died. We can use the `Start()` Method to set the `highscore` Text.

**Set HighScore Text:**

```cs
void Start() {
    // Set highscore Text to the current HighScore.
    highscore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighScore", 0.0f).ToString("0");
}
```

Comment: Why not using `float` and skip the rounding?

Comment: Because it will be shown as the highscore and the float could be a number with a lot of decimal places. Resulting in a huge scoretext or you needing to round anyway.

Comment: No you just need to use `ToString(format)` and provide the desired [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) you want for displaying here e.g. `ToString("0")` as OP had it or `ToString("D")` for decimal .. always use accurate values during calculations instead of rounding!

Comment: Okay thanks for the tipp, will edit my answer accordingly.